# Redirect community users from one domain to another (same org)

Tags: community, customer-community, redirect, custom-domain

We set up communities in our system to differentiate between regions. So we have a domain set up for .ca and another .com

Example: mycompany.community.ca
mycompany.community.com

We have learned that this wasn't necessary and now we are trying to consolidate our community sites to just one: mycompany.community.com

I want to figure out how to redirect all current users who may have bookmarked the .ca site to the .com site when they go to that page. (making this seamless for clients)

Simple URL redirect does not work because of the domains being different.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution here would be to use the [Apex class UrlRewriter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter_reference.htm) to redirect users based on the URL. You can associate this logic with a Visualforce page or a Lightning Component that runs the code upon initialization.

The UrlRewriter class can be used to preserve query string parameters if necessary, so this makes it a good solution to handle all possible bookmarked links your users may have.

Comment: Thank you EvanSteeleSFDC.
I didn't realize a response was received here, but certainly appreciate your time. I am looking forward to testing this!